# Obtaining the original unchanged Theme

Tags: themes, child-theme

Quite a few months back, I had used a third party theme v 2.9 in my wordpress site. I made a few custom changes to css/.php based on my needs. Now, I plan to upgrade the theme to v3.8.

Before doing that, I wanted to get the diff of changes that I had made to ver 2.9. As I didn't have a copy of the original theme, I contacted the developers of the theme; unfortunately, they also don't seem to have a copy of that.

What are my options to obtain the diff, get an original copy of the theme? Does wp store a copy of original theme somewhere? My site is hosted on bluehost.

Thank You.

Comment: Is your theme or your WordPress on version 2.9? If you made the changes with FTP, none of the original files are stored.

Comment: That is the problem making edits to a theme, I will always hammer on making edits or customizations in a child theme.  There is no way we can help you based on your question, it is very faque. On the other hand, recommodations are off topic. BTW, if you are still using wordpress 2.9 and want to move to wordpress 3.8 (that is what I make of your question), you'll be better of creating a new theme from scratch, as wordpress changed a heck of a lot since 2.9.

Comment: Close-voted as **too localized**, since the Theme in question is from a third-party, commercial Theme shop. You'll need to contact ElegantThemes support.

Comment: @PieterGoosen What makes this question as fake? I am genuinely trying to figure out a solution to a problem that I am facing and have tried to convey as much relevant information as I could. But I appreciate your feedback regarding posting on wordpress.se. FWIW, it's not wp v 2.9 but theme v2.9 I understand its a 3p theme, but the issue could have happened with any other free theme as well - I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This is what you use version control for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress doesn't store a copy of themes.

I see several options:

- Find out why the creator of the theme doesn't have a copy of the theme at version 2.9. It is really weird that any serious developer wouldn't keep a copy of old versions.
- Check your own backups.
- Ask your hosting provider if he has backups.
- How did you get the theme in the first place? Maybe you still have a copy in your Downloads folder or Mail Inbox?

Comment: I was surprised too. Perhaps it's their policy not to give away old revisions. Elegant Themes. I'll try to find the dev box which I used to create the website. I hope the original version is still present somewhere.

Comment: AFAIK, some of their old themes used Tim Thumb. Giving away an old version means giving away a vulnerable theme.

Comment: @RRikesh but I'm already using it.

Comment: Learn to use [Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) instead

Comment: I know, everything accepted. Guilty as charged. But I need to fix this before everything else :(

Comment: Okay, I found the original theme on one of the dev boxes. Thanks @kraftner